# Connect Ubuntu on Raspberry Pi with iPad pro via USC-C port

Tags: raspberrypi, usb-c

Currently, it is possible to connect Raspberry Pi / Raspbian to an iPad Pro via the USB-C port.  I am interested in if there is a similar capability available with Ubuntu for Raspberry Pi.  Ubuntu offers several advantages, not least of which is an easy install of Minikube.  Can anyone help?